# read new data into array of names from input.txt

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, compiler-errors

I keep getting this error for the while loop: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException;
This is under: Read new data into the array of names from "Input.txt" one String per line, and places them in an array. The number of Strings in the file must be the same as the number of cells in the array.

```
    // Open an input textfile named "Input.txt".
    File f = new File("Input.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(f);
    System.out.println("\nThe array contents:");

    // Read new data into the array of names from "Input.txt" one String per line, and places them in an array. 
    //The number of Strings in the file must be the same as the number of cells in the array.
    String[] input = new String [5];

    int k=0;
    while (inputFile.hasNext())
    {
        String str = inputFile.nextLine();
        input[k]=str;
        k++;
    }
    inputFile.close();




    //Print the new array contents on the screen
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter("Input.txt");
    for(String str : array)
        pw.println(str);
    pw.close();

}

/**
 * Method printOnScreen sends the entire contents of an 
 * array to the Screen using an "enhanced for" loop.
 * 
 * @param array the array of Strings be printed on Screen
 * 
 */
public static void printOnScreen(String[] args)
{
    for(String val : args)
        System.out.println(val);
}
```

Comment: Try putting the lines in an "ArrayList" and then use the "toArray()" method on the "ArrayList".

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`, it means your file has more than 5 lines and String array is just of length 5 so exception is thrown.
If you want to read 5 names from file 'Input.txt' then break the loop when k>5

```
while (inputFile.hasNext())
{   
    if(k>5) break;
    String str = inputFile.nextLine();
    input[k]=str;
    k++;
}
```

or if you want to read whole file, then you need to use array whose size is not defined when created, something like dynamic array: ArrayList

```
List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();

while (inputFile.hasNext())
{
    String str = inputFile.nextLine();
    input.add(str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your array size is short. If you are not sure about array size I suggest you to use ArrayList.

```
List<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();

int k=0;
while (inputFile.hasNext())
{
    String str = inputFile.nextLine();
    input.add(str);
}
inputFile.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

working example

```
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("d:\\myFile.txt"));

        String str;

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((str = input.readLine()) != null) {
            list.add(str);
        }

        String[] stringArr = list.toArray(new String[0]);

        System.out.println("\nThe array contents:");
        for (String val : stringArr)
            System.out.println(val);

    }

}
```

**Output**

The array contents:

```
stack
overflow
is 
good
```

**Text File Input** `myFile.txt`

```
stack
overflow
is 
good
```